# Umbraco IE error in tinymce3tinymceCompress.aspx

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce, umbraco

When using the latest Release version (4.0.4.2) of Umbraco, the tinymce3 control fails to show/load in the backoffice of umbraco.

Instead a JavaScript error is shown:

--- ERROR CONTENT ---
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 1
Char: 14609
Code: 0

### URI: http://example.com/umbraco/plugins/tinymce3/tinymce3tinymceCompress.aspx?rnd=5c8e3f37-f32a-481f-a795-c4f6bc57057e&module=gzipmodule&themes=umbraco&plugins=contextmenu,table,umbracomacro,paste,inlinepopups,media,umbracocss,advimage,advlink,noneditable&languages=en

Everything else runs fine in all other browsers, but in IE 6+7+8 this JS error shows.

Server info:
Windows 2008
IIS 7
Classic App Pool (Have also tried integrated app pool)

Help appriciated, have tried acertified Umbraco company (they installed and have setup the solution, but they kind of gave up, and we only discovered the issue after the first 6 customers was up and running on the single installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Umbraco adds the width like "100,200", where 100 is the value defined on the Richtext Editor datatype, and the value 200 is the value defined in the tinyMceConfig.config file.

In my case I had "100,100%" because I wanted to have a width of 100% on the Rich text editor in the back-end of Umbraco. I finally found the solution after digging a little into the debugger of IE 8, the Umbraco source and tinymce source.

The solution is to add the following to the tinyMceConfig.config

```
<tinymceConfig>
   <customConfig>
      <config key="width ">100%</config>
   </customConfig>
</tinymceConfig>
```

It is CRITICAL to remember the space after the "width" between the config key brackets, else the javascript bug breaks the page in IE 6+7+8.

I hope this will help others.

PS.
I also found a secondary reference for the same solution/error:
http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst8108_Quick-tip-set-Richtext-editor-at-100-width.aspx